# PHP google contact api how to retrive phone number

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-client

Is there a way to retrieve contact phone number with Google contact API
I developed PHP script to retrieve google contact using V2 and it works fine but I am getting only emails and name of the contact, I also need to retrieve a phone number.

Below is my code
index.php file

```
  session_start();
```

//include google api library

```
 require_once '/usr/share/nginx/html/dev/gcontact/vendor/autoload.php';// or wherever autoload.php is located

 $google_client_id = 'google_client_id';
 $google_client_secret = 'google_client_secret';
 $google_redirect_uri = 'http://localhost/dev/gcontact/callback.php';
 $client = new Google_Client();
 $client -> setApplicationName('My application name');
 $client -> setClientid($google_client_id);
 $client -> setClientSecret($google_client_secret);
 $client -> setRedirectUri($google_redirect_uri);
 $client -> setAccessType('online');

 $client -> setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts','https://www.google.com/m8/feeds','https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/user','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'));

 echo $googleImportUrl = $client -> createAuthUrl();
```

Callback.php

```
                    require_once '/usr/share/nginx/html/dev/gcontact/vendor/autoload.php';// or wherever autoload.php is located
                    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
                        $auth_code = $_GET["code"];
                        $_SESSION['google_code'] = $auth_code;  
                    }
                    $google_client_id = 'google_client_id';
                    $google_client_secret = 'google_client_secret';
                    $google_redirect_uri = 'http://localhost/dev/gcontact/callback.php';

            if(isset($_SESSION['google_code'])) {


                $auth_code = $_SESSION['google_code'];
                $max_results = 500;
                $fields=array(
                    'code'=>  urlencode($auth_code),
                    'client_id'=>  urlencode($google_client_id),
                    'client_secret'=>  urlencode($google_client_secret),
                    'redirect_uri'=>  urlencode($google_redirect_uri),
                    'grant_type'=>  urlencode('authorization_code')
                );
                $post = '';
                foreach($fields as $key=>$value)
                {
                    $post .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
                }
                $post = rtrim($post,'&');
                $result = curl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',$post);

                $response =  json_decode($result);
                $accesstoken = $response->access_token;

                $url = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results='.$max_results.'&alt=json&v=3.0&oauth_token='.$accesstoken;
                $client = new Google_Client();
                $client->setAccessToken($accesstoken);
                $google_oauthV2 = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
                $gpUserProfile = $google_oauthV2->userinfo->get();
                $browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                $user_time = date('D M d Y H:i:s O');
                $xmlresponse =  curl($url);
                $contacts = json_decode($xmlresponse,true);
                $return = array();
                if (!empty($contacts['feed']['entry'])) {
                    foreach($contacts['feed']['entry'] as $contact) {
                        $num = isset($cnt['gd$phoneNumber'][0]['$t'])? $cnt['gd$phoneNumber'][0]['$t']:'0000000000';
                        $num =  $cnt['gd$phoneNumber'][0]['$t'];
                       //retrieve Name and email address  
                        $return[] = array (
                            'name'=> $contact['title']['$t'],
                            'email' => $contact['gd$email'][0]['address'],
                            'phone' => $num // this always gives 0000000000
                        );
                    }               
                }

                $google_contacts = $return;
                //echo count($google_contacts); 
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($google_contacts); exit;
                makeRequest($gpUserProfile['name'],$gpUserProfile['email'],$user_time,$browser);

                unset($_SESSION['google_code']);

            }


            function curl($url, $post = "") {
                $curl = curl_init();
                $userAgent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                //The URL to fetch. This can also be set when initializing a session with curl_init().
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
                //TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
                //The number of seconds to wait while trying to connect.
                if ($post != "") {
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 5);
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
                }
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
                //The contents of the "User-Agent: " header to be used in a HTTP request.
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
                //To follow any "Location: " header that the server sends as part of the HTTP header.
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
                //To automatically set the Referer: field in requests where it follows a Location: redirect.
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
                //The maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute.
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
                //To stop cURL from verifying the peer's certificate.
                $contents = curl_exec($curl);
                curl_close($curl);
                return $contents;
            }
```

Comment: have you tried doing a print_r($contact)  to see where it is.   might help you map it to the right var.

Comment: Yes, but there is no phone number in the list.

Comment: because it hasn't been added

Comment: so I need to know how to add number?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Contacts API allows client applications to view and update a [user's contacts](https://contacts.google.com/). Contacts are stored in the user's Google Account; most Google services have access to the contact list.

Your client application can use the Google Contacts API to create new contacts, edit or delete existing contacts, and query for contacts that match particular criteria.   If the current authenticated user has not added the information for the contact then you are not going to be able to see the information.   Google contacts api can only return the data that it has.   This is the same for the new google people api.   I would also recommend that you switch to the google people api its the newer api and much easier to use.

Comment: The number is in the list already but I am unable to retrieve, maybe there is some mistake in my code

Comment: If the data isnt there the the user who you have authenticated needs to add it in https://contacts.google.com/

Comment: I am not sure, how to add, please tell me

Comment: Go to https://contacts.google.com/ find the user who you want to have a phone numer.   Add a phone number.    https://contacts.google.com/ is a web application if you have issues using it you may want to try asking a question on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/